# Using a null value from an array in prepared MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and can't come to a proper solution. I have an array of data in which some items are null. They are used in prepared statement which looks as follows:

```
$query = "insert into stocktake_details 
(created_at, created_by, deleted_at, deleted_by, department_id, edit_flag, full_cost, id, is_damaged, is_expired, is_synced, location_id, orientation, orientation_order,
            position_number, product_id, product_name, product_size_id, quantity, quantity_units, shelf_number, stocktake_id, store_locations_id, total_packed_items, unit_cost, unit_of_measure, updated_at, updated_by, user_id) 

values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$rowdata =  array_values((array)($data));

            $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
            $product_id = $data->product_id;
            $statement->execute($rowdata);
```

However, in the prepared statement the null gets converted to 'null'. I have seen some suggestions which mentioned bind parameters but I am unsure as to how am I supposed to use them with an array of items?

Comment: Inspect the `$rowdata` array.  Are they actually nulls, or strings called 'null'?

Comment: Can the columns contain NULL values? You should add your table schema.

Comment: @jeroen yes the columns are nullable, the database structure is definitely fine, that's why I didn't include it. When I try to run the query through PMA with removing the quotes it works fine. 
EatPeanutButter we tried both approaches and in both cases had the same problem, except when it was an actual null, it was just leaving a blank space between two commas in the query

Answer (score -1):

Binding parameters is actually not -that- hard:

```
// $statement is the prepared statement reference.
// $parameters is an array of all the parameters and as first entry the query itself in order of ? (for mysqli)
// ie. ('select 1...', '1', '1') etc.

$this->DetermineParameterTypes($parameters);
for($key = 1; $key < count($parameters); $key++)
    $parameters[$key] = &$parameters[$key];

// Bind parameters
call_user_func_array(array($statement, "bind_param"), $parameters);

    /**
     * Determine the types of the prepared statement parameters
     *
     * @param array by ref $parameters Parameters
     *
     */
    private function DetermineParameterTypes(&$parameters)
    {
        // Remove first argument this is the $query object
        array_shift($parameters);

        // Determine the parameter types
        $types = '';
        foreach($parameters as $param)
        {
            if((is_int($param) || is_bool($param)) && strpos($param, '.') === false)
                $types .= 'i';              //integer
            elseif (is_float($param) || is_double($param))
                $types .= 'd';              //double
            elseif (is_string($param))
                $types .= 's';              //string
            elseif (is_array($param))
                $types .= 'b';              //blob and unknown
            elseif (is_null($param))
                $types .= 's';              //set null to string type
            else
                $types .= '?';
        }
        array_unshift($parameters, $types);
    }
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but what exactly is this supposed to accomplish?

Comment: He asks that he doesn't know how to bind parameters, this will bind parameters for the query, since he already uses the prepared statement, which by itself is a lot better then sql injection code that I'm assuming if the parameters aren't bound already.. -.-.. I quote ". I have seen some suggestions which mentioned bind parameters but I am unsure as to how am I supposed to use them with an array of items?" ... and the above is the answer to that..